# Тире после двоеточия

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли тире в выделенном месте? Какое правило регламентирует его постановку в данном случае?

> Он носился исключительно в сочетании с легкой блузой: шарф и белая блуза (—) а вот потом...

Answer (score 1):

Он носился исключительно в сочетании с легкой блузой: шарф и белая блуза — а вот потом..

1) **Двоеточие ставится перед пояснительной конструкцией,** у Розенталя:
Возможна также постановка двоеточия (чтобы избежать двух тире).
*Предложен и другой путь: использование некоторых видов морских растений — водорослей, богатых многими ценными веществами.*
[§ 23. Пояснительные конструкции](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119#pp119)

2) **Тире здесь авторский, неосновной знак перед сочинительным союзом А**, обозначает увеличенную паузу со значением элемента неожиданности (интриги) в развитии событий.
У Лопатина (ПАС): *Я спешу туда ж — а там уже весь город.*
[Лопатин. Знаки препинания в сложносочиненном предложении.](http://orthographia.ru/punctum.php?paragraph=pg114.php)